# hacer un if en el where de un select

Tags: mysql

como puedo hacer un if en el where en mysql

quiero validar esto

```
$parametro= mujer
$parametro= Hombre
$parametro= Indistinto

select * from tabla s
```

si campo `s.sexo  = $parametro OR` si el parametro se llama Indistinto que me traiga toda la tabla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes crear un procedimiento almacenado al que le pases como parámetro el sexo y filtre la data de acuerdo a eso:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS obtenerData //

CREATE PROCEDURE 
  obtenerData( parametro VARCHAR(20) )
BEGIN
   IF(parametro = 'Indistinto') THEN
      -- Devuelves toda la tabla si es 'Indistinto'
      SELECT * FROM tabla 
   ELSE
      -- Sino devuelves data de acuerdo al parámetro
      SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE tabla.sexo = parametro
   ENDIF
   ;  
END 
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Luego llamas a ese procedimiento almacenado según tu parámetro

```
call obtenerData('Hombre');
call obtenerData('Mujer');
call obtenerData('Indistinto');
```

Answer (score 4):

Seria así:

```
select * from tabla s Where (s.sexo = $parametro) Or ($parametro = 'Indistinto')
```

Comment: Pondría los paréntesis fuera de ambas condiciones, para que tome como condición independiente, en el caso de que el "Where" tuviera otra cosa. Por si entrevero, la condición sería: `where [Condiciones] AND (s.sexo = $parametro Or $parametro = 'Indistinto')`